# How do I limit user input to only array list integers?? Java

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch

I want to be able to show the user my array items and then prompt them to choose from the listed items. If they choose a number that isn't in my array, I want to be able to catch it with my try-catch block. I am new to this.

```
int[] temperatures = {11, -2, 12, 2, 10, 32, 55, 102, 69, 77, 88, 90, 101};


try{
System.out.println("The temperatures in the city this year were " + Arrays.toString(temperatures));
System.out.println("Select a range by choosing two temperatures from the list above");
int temp1= keyboard.nextInt();
int temp2 = keyboard.nextInt();

//what would I include to make user input invalid if it doesn't match my array??


}


catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("You did not select a valid temperature from the list. Please select two from the list.");
}
```

Comment: Do you really specifically need to handle it in the catch block?